# How many reports can Ben type in "m" minutes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Benjamin can type 1 report in *h* hours, how many reports can he type in
>   *m* minutes?

I feel really bad asking this question after doing 100s of challenging math problems. Today I struggled with this laughable problem.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: How many reports can he type in 60 minutes? 120 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can type $1$ report in $h$ hours, then we can convert hours to minutes, so: $$\frac{1}{h}\cdot\frac{1hour}{60min}$$ So that means I can type $1$ report every $60$ minutes. Hence, in $m$ minutes, I can type $\frac{m}{60}$ reports.

Comment: That's what I got as an answer but it wasn't an answer choice. Thanks for your time.